# Expandable Text Box Overflowing on Samsung Tablet

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on an older site based on Coppermine Photo Gallery (1.5.18).  I just changed the code on the comment entry box so that it has more rows and is expandable.  I've tested it with several devices/browsers all with satisfactory results, however when you bring it up on a Samsung Galaxy Tab A with Chrome there is an issue.  The field looks OK at first.  But when you type one line and hit return it overflows over the bottom of the containing cell.  Code here:

```
<td width="100%" class="tableb tableb_alternate">
    <textarea class="textinput" id="message" name="msg_body"  maxlength="{MAX_COM_LENGTH}" style="width: 100%; resize: vertical;" rows="6"></textarea>                              
</td>
```

Comment: please provide compiled html and css via 'snippet' functionality here

Comment: I haven't left a question here in a long time because the last time I did I got run over by all kinds of people telling me how dumb I was.  I see in the first couple minutes the question has been edited significantly and I've got a guy asking me to post snippets.

Comment: providing a code will let people help you. how do you suppose to get help without css?

Comment: The CSS is inline. It's in the example I gave already. I've seen questions with what appear to be hosted snippets. But it would seem I am not yet cool enough by SO standards to have such access. I don't have time to sign up for a third-party service for a question I may get no answer to. I also don't understand why my list of successful browser tests was removed, as well the Galaxy and tablet tags. Most of what I do on SO is search. SO is a great searchable resource.  But that will atrophy if people don't add new content.  Moderators treating people like stooges puts them on that road.